# Fields exporting out of order

Tags: export, issues

There seems to be a problem with home fields exporting out of order as soon as the first a "Home" field is output. I noticed this on my site and replicated it on the demo site (Civi 4.7.29 on Drupal). Examples:

On the demo site

- Selected fields: **phone-home-phone**, firstname, lastname, **email-home**
- Exported CSV: **phone-home-phone, email-home**, firstname, lastname

On my own site, example 1

- Selected fields: **email-home**, email-work, email-other, **phone-home-phone, phone-home-mobile, phone-home-voicemail**, contact id, firstname, lastname, **postalcode-home, city-home, state-home, country-home**, birthdate, gender.
- Exported CSV: **email-home, phone-home-phone, phone-home-mobile, phone-home-voicemail, postalcode-home, city-home, state-home, country-home**, email-work, email-other, contact id, firstname, lastname, birthdate, gender.

On my own site, example 2

- Selected fields: contact id, email-work, email-other, **phone-home-phone, phone-home-mobile, phone-home-voicemail, email-home**, firstname, lastname, **postalcode-home, city-home, state-home, country-home**, birthdate, gender.
- Exported CSV: contact id, email-work, email-other, **phone-home-phone, phone-home-mobile, phone-home-voicemail, email-home, postalcode-home, city-home, state-home, country-home**, firstname, lastname, birthdate, gender.

It seems I should submit this as a bug, but perhaps there's a fix I'm not aware of.

Comment: Is this still an issue in 5.3.1 & if so does it co-incide with locations where the label field !== the name field? (there is an open issue for that but TBH the symptoms are slightly different